# SSL certificate warning in asp site

Tags: ssl

I have an ASP web site that give a warning to visitors with red x (in chrome) and FireFox not verified when they try to login. see the picture [image: SSL Warning]

Please advise what it means and what I should do

thanks

Answer (score 0):

When a page is loaded via an HTTPS URL, the browser security model states that all resources referenced by that page should also be HTTPS URLs. Check your page for references to JavaScript, CSS, JPGs, etc. All of them should be using HTTPS when the main page is loaded by HTTPS.

If you have JavaScript that is dynamically loading content with XHR, you need to make sure the URLs you load match the scheme (HTTP or HTTPS) of the main page. This is particularly important for JavaScript that is intended to be reused on multiple HTML pages, some which are loaded via HTTP and some with are loaded via HTTPS.

Comment: the problem that after login the login page redirected to login.asp again then index.asp and it is done so using https but I want to use http when it goes to index.asp after successful login only any idea how to inspect that ?

Comment: also if possible any steps to use godaddy certificate on another host manually ?

Comment: The whole point of https is to provide protection against eavesdropping by third parties and to prevent injection of malicious content by man-in-the-middle scenarios. If any portion of your workflow is not https, then that portion can be exploited to attack or disrupt the entire workflow.  An HTTPS url that redirects to an HTTP URL is a step down in security and the browser rightly flags it as a potential security issue.

Comment: so what I can do to secure all resources like images , css , etc... ? and how to identify the secured part of the page from the none secured

Comment: as long as there is a "non-secured part of the page", the browser will flag the page as a security issue.  All parts of the page must be secured in order to call the page secure. Even placing the non-secured parts in an iframe is not enough - an https page that references an iframe with a non-https url will be flagged as a security issue. For static html, you should make sure all url references are https. For URLs built with JavaScript, you should build url references using the scheme of the main page URL so that all urls on an https page will be https urls.